# String object value evaluated as expression

Tags: r

I have a string variable and I would like to evaluate its value as an expression using `expression()`

Example:

```
>expression("Text")
expression("Text")

>a <- "Text"
>expression(a)
expression(a)
```

I want to do something to make `expression(a)` evaluate to `expression("Text")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you could write why you need it?

Because what you want makes no sense to me.

Type

```
?expression
```

and you will see:

```
expression returns a vector of type "expression" containing its arguments (unevaluated)
```

You would have to rewrite the function to make it do what you want.

If you wanted to fake it, you would do something like this (not recommended :) ):

```
paste("expression(", a, ")", sep="")
```

edit:
From ?expression you can see at the bottom, that as.expression(a) is what you needed

```
as.expression attempts to coerce its argument into an expression object
```

Comment: need it to display equations on a plot using ggplot. the equations are stored as strings in variables.

Comment: does this paste option help you?

Comment: no. that returns a string. "expression(a)" vs expression(a).

Comment: This is it then:     `as.expression(a)`

Comment: your post led me to this which worked: `evalexpr <- function(x) eval(parse(text = paste("expression(", x, ")", sep = "")))`

Comment: @user2183336 if that's what you you should update your question. `as.expression(a)` gives `expression("Text")`, which is what you said you wanted. `evalexpr(a)` gives `expression(Text)` (no quotes).